# Angular:How to clear network (API json) in console.?

Tags: angular, console

I work with platform Dashboad contains a lot of charts and we have live data APIs I need a clear network every time period.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck "Persist Logs" on Firefox and on Chrome.

Comment: Hi @JoHTVS, I need the solution in source code in component angular.